# How to access global variables from viewcontroller.mm in c++ program?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c

First of all i am new on objective C and Xcode .

Currently i am trying to do access a zip file on button click so for that i am using a libzip library which is written in C , so i wrote a C++ code to access the libzip library and now i am using objective C to which calls C++ 
methods on button click ..

Now i kept my zipfile in an app and with a Objective C code-snippet i am able to get path of the zip file, now my requirement is to pass that path of the zip file to the C++ class so that further operations can be done.

this is from where i am getting the file path
[image]

and this where i want to access file path.

[image]

Comment: Please describe the problem you're having. Objective-C is a superset of C, so you can use the library directly without a C++ wrapper. (And don't post pictures of text. Apple has not removed the Copy command from XCode.)

Comment: see currently i kept a zip file inside my ios app and i am trying to access that zip file on button click .. my zip file is in Documents directory can you please tell me what path should i give to access that zip file . ? i tried with - `/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3884BD6B-7D9F-4429-9A9A-BEA83491A287/unzip-test.app/zipfile3.zip`   and  `file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3884BD6B-7D9F-4429-9A9A-BEA83491A287/unzip-test.app/zipfile3.zip`    paths but still not able to find zip in code it is returning zip not present error.